# Bluemix Swift Mobile Client Access SDK when imported says no such module BMS Core and BMS Analytics show 35 errors due to which my build fails

Tags: swift, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

As per the instructions given on Bluemix site; I installed the Swift SDK

```
 pod use_frameworks!
 pod 'BMSSecurity'
```

and it shows this on my terminal:

[image: terminal]

Then, when I built the project, I got 36 build errors.

First of which is "no such module as `BMSCore`" when I can see that framework imported in the pod and 35 errors related to `BMSAnalytics`, which is again framework imported.

[image: error]

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Also, what is your version of CocoaPods?

Comment: One more quick thing to try is shutting down Xcode completely and reopening the `.xcworkspace` file after relaunching.

Comment: XCode version 7.2.1

Comment: Cocoapods version 1.0.1

Comment: I did quit xcode and did a open foodtracker.xcworkspace from terminal still got the same 36 errors.

Comment: I resolved the 'No such module BMSCore' error by creating a bridging header.h file and importing BMSCore there. However I am still getting these errors from BMS Analytics not sure why as i have not even edited these files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These build errors are due to the incompatibility between two of the BMSSecurity dependencies (BMSCore and BMSAnalyticsAPI) and the version of Xcode you are using (7.2.1). The latest versions of these 2 frameworks only support Xcode 7.3 and higher, as explained in the BMSCore Github [README](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-clientsdk-swift-core/blob/master/README.md). If you want to continue using Xcode 7.2, you can use BMSCore 1.0.3 instead.

So, there are 2 possible solutions here:

1. Upgrade Xcode to version 7.3
2. Add the following line to your Podfile: `pod 'BMSCore', '~> 1.0.3'`

Option 1 is recommended since only Xcode 7.3+ will be supported in future releases of BMSSecurity.

Comment: Thank you Anthony. Upgrading to Xcode 7.3 resolve the build errors I was getting.

Answer (score 0):

Are you opening FoodTracker.xcworkspace ?? please open .xcworkspace after pod install..